# Enable CORS from a Node.JS Callback Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, twilio, twilio-api

I'm attempting to use Twilio Functions to handle token generation for my Twilio application. I previously was using a Node.js + Express Server to accomplish this, but I do not know how to figure out enable CORS in this type of environment. 
My Client Code looks like this:

```
$('#new-twilio').click(function(){
        var toNum = this.value;
        if(token == undefined) {
            $.getJSON('https://my-twilio-function/endpoint').done(function(data){
                token = data.token;
                Twilio.Device.setup(token, {debug: true});
                Twilio.Device.ready(function(device){
                    Twilio.Device.connect({"PhoneNumber": toNum});  
                });
            }).fail(function(error){
                alert("Failure!");
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        } else {
            Twilio.Device.connect({"PhoneNumber": toNum});
        }
    });
```

My function code looks like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    const ClientCapability = require('twilio').jwt.ClientCapability;
    const responseHeaders = {  
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type, accept",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    let identity = "sampleIdentity";
    const capability = new ClientCapability({
      accountSid: context.ACCOUNT_SID,
      authToken: context.AUTH_TOKEN
    });
    capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(identity));
    capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
      applicationSid: context.TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID
    }));
    console.log(capability.toJwt());
    callback(null, {headers: responseHeaders, identity: identity, token: capability.toJwt()});
```

};

 Worth noting, the console.log proves that this function is returning the exact token I need, but I continue to get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-twilio-function/endpoint. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Obviously, my twilio function is at a real URL. As much as I google, I cannot find how to allow access control to this type of node method.

Comment: It would be interesting to see where you import that function, and what `callback` does

Comment: Does this help? https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions/faq#how-do-i-send-cors-headers I couldn't help but notice they don't mention support for "*" (or lack of it).

Comment: @adeneo, the callback is supposed to return a  piece of data to whatever called the function. If it's a javascript object it will be returned as JSON, you can do TwiML too.

Comment: @Will, The link helps to the point that I can attach headers and get it not to error out, but I cannot seem to retrieve the token now. I can't find documentation on the supported methods of the Twilio.Response method. I can fumble around and try to use other HttpResponse methods or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This client code ended up working:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();
  const ClientCapability = require('twilio').jwt.ClientCapability;
  const response = new Twilio.Response();
  response.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  response.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  response.appendHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let identity = "sampleIdentity";
  const capability = new ClientCapability({
    accountSid: context.ACCOUNT_SID,
    authToken: context.AUTH_TOKEN
  });
  capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(identity));
  capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
    applicationSid: context.TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID
  }));
  response.setBody({identity: identity, token: capability.toJwt()})
  console.log(capability.toJwt());
  callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm glad to see that K. Rhoda sorted out the issue. I just wanted to make obvious what made it work.

There is a [custom response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions/environment#callback) you can access from `Twilio.Response` within the Function. The response is initialized like:

```
const response = new Twilio.Response();
```

and then has the following useful methods:

```
// set the body of the response
response.setBody(body);

// set a header for the response
response.appendHeader(key, value);

// set all the headers for the response
response.setHeaders(obj);

// set the status code for the response
response.setStatusCode(200);
```

You can then send that response using the callback function, like so:

```
callback(null, response);
```

Comment: Could I suggest that you (presuming Twilio developer-evangelist means some connection to the company) create token generation templates? I see this as a common use case.

Comment: I do indeed work for Twilio :) That's a great suggestion, and having it work with CORS is an important part of that. I've actually started my own repo of [useful functions](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/) and token generation is on the list to be done (PRs are welcome ;) ). We are also incorporating more templates as we work on the platform. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything above didn't work because i had "**Check for valid Twilio signature**" checked in my fuction (by default) and made requests without signature.

After I unchecked it, answers above worked. So pay attention to whether you have this checked and if so whether your request has proper signature.

Comment: How did you uncheck it?

Comment: i used classic functions back then. they had a checkbox for that. not sure about new functions